# error: invalid suffix "x" on integer constant

Tags: c++

I am getiing the mentioned error for the following code:

```
#include "iostream"

#include <stdint.h>
#define CONTINUE 0x00
#define END 0x80
#define POWER7 0x

int main(){
        uint8_t *s = new uint8_t[ 10 ];
        int res = 0;
        int t = 2;
        res=t & POWER7;
        s [ 0]= ( t >POWER7 ? CONTINUE : END ) | res ;
        return 0;
}
```

This code was working fine, but after doing some modification, am geting the error.As I am new in c++, so quite unable to understand the error.

Error:

```
smple.cpp:11:10: error: invalid suffix "x" on integer constant
smple.cpp:12:15: error: invalid suffix "x" on integer constan
```

t

Comment: Of course you get that message; what do you expect `0x` to mean?

Comment: (Check the `#define POWER7`, perhaps you weren't using that macro/damaged it)

Answer (score 3):

You are using incorrect numeric literal

```
#define POWER7 0x
```

in statements

```
   res=t & POWER7;
    s [ 0]= ( t >POWER7 ? CONTINUE : END ) | res ;
```

According to the C++ Standard hexadecimal integer literal is defined the following way:

```
hexadecimal-literal:
0x hexadecimal-digit
0X hexadecimal-digit
hexadecimal-literal hexadecimal-digit
```

that is after 0x or 0X there must be at least one hexadecimal digit.

Comment: I have copy pest your code, still getting same error.

Comment: @user2422669 What code did you copy and past?!

Comment: because my code was same, still was getting error. Thank you